# Which tense after 'would I... if.... ?'

Tags: grammar, tenses, conditionals

I am struggling on a sentence here. Let me show u what I come up with;

```
Would I fail if I won't study?
```

In this sentence I am trying to indicate a possibility but I am not sure if I use this part  correct : `if I won't study`

which tense should I be using there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sentence you're looking for is:

> **Will** I fail if I **don't** study?

The *if*-clause in English takes an ordinary present-tense verb in this construction. This is a *present conditional*, which indication a condition about a present or future action.

You could also write this:

> **Would** I fail if I **didn't** study?

This indicates a hypothetical condition. If you actually want to indicate a counter-factual condition about a past event, you need to use the perfect:

> **Would** I **have failed** if I **hadn't** studied?

Comment: The "hypothetical" form is properly called the *subjunctive*.

Answer (score 4):

It's rare to use the future tense with *if*. Speakers would use either the past tense or present as follows:

> Would I fail if I didn't study?
>
> Will I fail if I don't study?

It's more common to use the present tense ("don't study") when the main clause has "will" (future).

Of thes two alternatives, the first tends to indicat a more "hypothetical" suggestion: it's asking about possible universes, whether or not you actually have any intention of studying. In the second case, there's a presupposition that you're actually considering studying.

Answer (score 3):

Since no one else so far has actually addressed "won't" (the act of willfully declining to do a thing), I'll just add that the proper construction using that particular word would be:

> Will I fail if I won't study?